# How to print to the console?

Tags: android, android-studio

Been looking at others questions on here and they seem very complicated. Say I just want to print `Hello World`, how would I do this? And where would I see the output?

Edit: This is on Android Studio

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: you can print on console somthing like  System.out.println ("hello world");

Comment: Android apps don't really use the console, they're meant to be graphical apps.  There is a system log you can use for debug messages, but its a shared log used by every app in the system, so using it for real output is extremely frowned upon-  you clutter the log for every other use of it.  Log statements should be used only for temporary debug messages removed before shipping or major errors.

Comment: how about you watch some lessons before asking a question? How about learning very-basics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Log.xxx(); methods to print a log

```
   Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: Hello World!");
```

here, i is for info.

There are many types check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Comment: So I just added this in and ran my app. But where do I see the output?

Comment: check the android monitor in your android studio, click alt+6 for windows/linux pcs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Log` class. Most people do something like:

```
private final String TAG = YourClass.class.getSimpleName();

//debug log
Log.d(TAG, "Your message here");
//error log
Log.e(TAG, "Your message here");
//info log
Log.i(TAG, "Your message here");
//verbose log
Log.v(TAG, "Your message here");
```

You can also use:

```
System.out.println("Your string here");
```

Comment: where does the output from "System.out.println()" end up?